# discord.py Проблема с bot.event

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Хотел сделать код для заявок на сервер, с использованием кнопок, но столкнулся с проблемой, что в @bot.event мне нужно inter и нужно ctx, но когда добавляешь ctx выдаёт ошибку, что нету аргумента, а когда нету ctx, то проблемы с кодом, потому что он там используется. Возможно как-то заменить это или переписать немного код? Буду  благодарен за любую помощь.
Сам код:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_button_click(inter, ctx):
    if inter.component.id == 'zay1':
        
        ticket_created_embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Заявка",
        description=f"""Приветствую, {ctx.author.name}! Напишите в чат ваш **тег*\nи ожидайте ответа администрации.""", color=0xff00ff
    ) 
        ticket_created_embed.set_footer(text='С ув. администрация сервера')
    
        overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False),
        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True)}

        ticket = await ticket_category.create_text_channel(
        f"{ctx.author.name}-{ctx.author.discriminator}", overwrites=overwrites
    )
        await inter.reply(f'#{ctx.author.name}-{ctx.author.discriminator} - ваш канал заявки.', ephemeral=True)

        row = ActionRow(Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label='Закрыть', custom_id='zay2'))
        await ticket.send(ctx.author.mention, embed=ticket_created_embed, components=[row])
             if inter.component.id == 'zay2':
                    await ctx.channel.delete()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `inter`, как если бы использовали `ctx`:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_button_click(inter, ctx):
    if inter.component.id == 'zay1':
        
        ticket_created_embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Заявка",
        description=
            f"""Приветствую, {ctx.author.name}! Напишите в чат ваш **тег*\nи ожидайте ответа администрации.""", 
            color=0xff00ff
    ) 
        ticket_created_embed.set_footer(text='С ув. администрация сервера')
    
        overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False),
        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True)}

        ticket = await ticket_category.create_text_channel(
        f"{inter.user.name}-{ctx.author.discriminator}", overwrites=overwrites
    )
        await inter.reply(f'#{ctx.author.name}-{ctx.author.discriminator} - ваш канал заявки.', ephemeral=True)

        row = ActionRow(Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label='Закрыть', custom_id='zay2'))
        await ticket.send(inter.user.mention, embed=ticket_created_embed, components=[row])
             if inter.component.id == 'zay2':
                    await inter.channel.delete()
```

Документация: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html

Comment: Какой тупой вопрос я задавал 5 месяцев назад, ужас, извините 

Comment: Со всеми бывает ;)

Answer (score 0):

дела в том что нужно разделить код где использоваться `ctx`,
тойсть написать все функции связанные с **ctx** написать в одной функции, а всё что связанно с `inter` в другую функцию

```
@bot.event
  async def on_button_click(ctx):
        сюда код 
@bot.event
  async def on_button_click(inter):
        сюда код
```

Comment: Если разделить код, то как мне отследить какая кнопка была нажата пользователем, чтобы выполнить создание канала после нажатия?